# how to restrict the access to service in different modules

Tags: java, spring, rest, servlets, jersey

My requirement is to call the services from two different modules.But, Some urls can allow both modules,some urls allow for specific to that module.
Below is my current configuration for achieving that

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>animals</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.lion,com.dog</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>animals</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/lion/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>animals</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dogs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For example if I have a service called as `'barking'` this service is located in `com.dog` package.Now i can call this service using two urls like below

```
/lions/barking
/dogs/barking
```

As per my requirement `/lions/barking` should show `404` error.But it gives the response.

But some url both should work.Irrespective of where the service is located.

```
/lions/eat
/dogs/eat
```

How to do the configuration to achieve that functionality

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Create super classes for Lion and Dog and extend them to match the api endpoints that you require.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a "http Servlet Request Filter" to customise and configure/serve the requests as per your business requirements.**

Please find the sample code below:

```
public class RequestUrlFilter implements Filter {

    private static List<String> validUrls = new ArrayList<>();

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        //Load the valid list of urls here
        validUrls.add("/lions/eat"); 
        validUrls.add("/dogs/eat");
        validUrls.add("/dogs/barking");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain filterChain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

            if(validUrls.contains(((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI()) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
            } else {
                //Error Response
                RequestDispatcher rd = (HttpServletRequest)request.getRequestDispatcher("Error.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```